# Using XPath in PMD to find duplicate expressions

Tags: java, xpath, pmd

I want to use PMD to find Common Subexpression of the form

```
z = a +b;
q = a +b;
```

for Java code.

I know the CPD tool exists for things like this but there I will also receive copied functions etc. that have matches in the file. I only want to find duplicate expressions that are connected with a Binary Operator.

When analyzing a small code example `z = a + b` the following structure appears per BlockStatement:

```
└─ BlockStatement
   └─ Statement
      └─ StatementExpression
         ├─ PrimaryExpression
         │  └─ PrimaryPrefix        //   z 
         │     └─ Name
         ├─ AssignmentOperator
         └─ Expression
            └─ AdditiveExpression   //   +
               ├─ PrimaryExpression
               │  └─ PrimaryPrefix  //   a 
               │     └─ Name
               └─ PrimaryExpression
                  └─ PrimaryPrefix  //   b
                     └─ Name
```

I know I somehow have to check if the count of an AdditiveExpression appears more than once in my method by I cannot get it working.
One aspect where I lack understanding is, whether I need to compare all 3 parts of the expression or if I just can compare the inner node AdditiveExpression because from there on the duplicate expressions are the same.

Wrong approaches:

//AdditiveExpression[count(.) > 0]

//AdditiveExpression[.=../../../../BlockStatement/Statement/StatementExpression/Expression]/AdditiveExpression]

Edit 1: Adding the XML file for the following java Example:

```
public class Example{
    public static void main(final String[] args){
    int i = 5;
    int k = 10;
    int z,h;
    z = i + k;
    h = i + k;
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<CompilationUnit Image='' PackageName='' declarationsAreInDefaultPackage='true'>
    <TypeDeclaration Image=''>
        <ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration Abstract='false' BinaryName='Example' Default='false' Final='false' Image='Example' Interface='false' Local='false' Modifiers='1' Native='false' Nested='false' NonSealed='false' PackagePrivate='false' Private='false' Protected='false' Public='true' Sealed='false' SimpleName='Example' Static='false' Strictfp='false' Synchronized='false' Transient='false' TypeKind='CLASS' Volatile='false'>
            <ClassOrInterfaceBody AnonymousInnerClass='false' EnumChild='false' Image=''>
                <ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration AnonymousInnerClass='false' EnumChild='false' Image='' Kind='METHOD'>
                    <MethodDeclaration Abstract='false' Arity='1' Default='false' Final='false' Image='' InterfaceMember='false' Kind='METHOD' MethodName='main' Modifiers='17' Name='main' Native='false' PackagePrivate='false' Private='false' Protected='false' Public='true' Static='true' Strictfp='false' Synchronized='false' SyntacticallyAbstract='false' SyntacticallyPublic='true' Transient='false' Void='true' Volatile='false'>
                        <ResultType Image='' Void='true' returnsArray='false' />
                        <MethodDeclarator Image='main' ParameterCount='1'>
                            <FormalParameters Image='' ParameterCount='1' Size='1'>
                                <FormalParameter Abstract='false' Array='true' ArrayDepth='1' Default='false' ExplicitReceiverParameter='false' Final='true' Image='' Modifiers='32' Native='false' PackagePrivate='true' Private='false' Protected='false' Public='false' Static='false' Strictfp='false' Synchronized='false' Transient='false' TypeInferred='false' Varargs='false' Volatile='false'>
                                    <Type Array='true' ArrayDepth='1' ArrayType='true' Image='' TypeImage='String'>
                                        <ReferenceType Array='true' ArrayDepth='1' Image=''>
                                            <ClassOrInterfaceType AnonymousClass='false' Array='true' ArrayDepth='1' Image='String' ReferenceToClassSameCompilationUnit='false' />
                                        </ReferenceType>
                                    </Type>
                                    <VariableDeclaratorId Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' ArrayType='true' ExceptionBlockParameter='false' ExplicitReceiverParameter='false' Field='false' Final='true' ForeachVariable='false' FormalParameter='true' Image='args' LambdaParameter='false' LocalVariable='false' Name='args' PatternBinding='false' ResourceDeclaration='false' TypeInferred='false' VariableName='args' />
                                </FormalParameter>
                            </FormalParameters>
                        </MethodDeclarator>
                        <Block Image='' containsComment='false'>
                            <BlockStatement Allocation='false' Image=''>
                                <LocalVariableDeclaration Abstract='false' Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' Default='false' Final='false' Image='' Modifiers='0' Native='false' PackagePrivate='true' Private='false' Protected='false' Public='false' Static='false' Strictfp='false' Synchronized='false' Transient='false' TypeInferred='false' VariableName='i' Volatile='false'>
                                    <Type Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' ArrayType='false' Image='' TypeImage='int'>
                                        <PrimitiveType Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' Boolean='false' Image='int' />
                                    </Type>
                                    <VariableDeclarator Image='' Initializer='true' Name='i'>
                                        <VariableDeclaratorId Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' ArrayType='false' ExceptionBlockParameter='false' ExplicitReceiverParameter='false' Field='false' Final='false' ForeachVariable='false' FormalParameter='false' Image='i' LambdaParameter='false' LocalVariable='true' Name='i' PatternBinding='false' ResourceDeclaration='false' TypeInferred='false' VariableName='i' />
                                        <VariableInitializer Image=''>
                                            <Expression Image='' StandAlonePrimitive='true'>
                                                <PrimaryExpression Image=''>
                                                    <PrimaryPrefix Image='' SuperModifier='false' ThisModifier='false'>
                                                        <Literal CharLiteral='false' DoubleLiteral='false' EscapedStringLiteral='5' FloatLiteral='false' Image='5' IntLiteral='true' LongLiteral='false' SingleCharacterStringLiteral='false' StringLiteral='false' TextBlock='false' TextBlockContent='5' ValueAsDouble='NaN' ValueAsFloat='NaN' ValueAsInt='5' ValueAsLong='5' />
                                                    </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                </PrimaryExpression>
                                            </Expression>
                                        </VariableInitializer>
                                    </VariableDeclarator>
                                </LocalVariableDeclaration>
                            </BlockStatement>
                            <BlockStatement Allocation='false' Image=''>
                                <LocalVariableDeclaration Abstract='false' Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' Default='false' Final='false' Image='' Modifiers='0' Native='false' PackagePrivate='true' Private='false' Protected='false' Public='false' Static='false' Strictfp='false' Synchronized='false' Transient='false' TypeInferred='false' VariableName='k' Volatile='false'>
                                    <Type Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' ArrayType='false' Image='' TypeImage='int'>
                                        <PrimitiveType Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' Boolean='false' Image='int' />
                                    </Type>
                                    <VariableDeclarator Image='' Initializer='true' Name='k'>
                                        <VariableDeclaratorId Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' ArrayType='false' ExceptionBlockParameter='false' ExplicitReceiverParameter='false' Field='false' Final='false' ForeachVariable='false' FormalParameter='false' Image='k' LambdaParameter='false' LocalVariable='true' Name='k' PatternBinding='false' ResourceDeclaration='false' TypeInferred='false' VariableName='k' />
                                        <VariableInitializer Image=''>
                                            <Expression Image='' StandAlonePrimitive='true'>
                                                <PrimaryExpression Image=''>
                                                    <PrimaryPrefix Image='' SuperModifier='false' ThisModifier='false'>
                                                        <Literal CharLiteral='false' DoubleLiteral='false' EscapedStringLiteral='10' FloatLiteral='false' Image='10' IntLiteral='true' LongLiteral='false' SingleCharacterStringLiteral='false' StringLiteral='false' TextBlock='false' TextBlockContent='10' ValueAsDouble='NaN' ValueAsFloat='NaN' ValueAsInt='10' ValueAsLong='10' />
                                                    </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                </PrimaryExpression>
                                            </Expression>
                                        </VariableInitializer>
                                    </VariableDeclarator>
                                </LocalVariableDeclaration>
                            </BlockStatement>
                            <BlockStatement Allocation='false' Image=''>
                                <LocalVariableDeclaration Abstract='false' Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' Default='false' Final='false' Image='' Modifiers='0' Native='false' PackagePrivate='true' Private='false' Protected='false' Public='false' Static='false' Strictfp='false' Synchronized='false' Transient='false' TypeInferred='false' VariableName='z' Volatile='false'>
                                    <Type Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' ArrayType='false' Image='' TypeImage='int'>
                                        <PrimitiveType Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' Boolean='false' Image='int' />
                                    </Type>
                                    <VariableDeclarator Image='' Initializer='false' Name='z'>
                                        <VariableDeclaratorId Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' ArrayType='false' ExceptionBlockParameter='false' ExplicitReceiverParameter='false' Field='false' Final='false' ForeachVariable='false' FormalParameter='false' Image='z' LambdaParameter='false' LocalVariable='true' Name='z' PatternBinding='false' ResourceDeclaration='false' TypeInferred='false' VariableName='z' />
                                    </VariableDeclarator>
                                    <VariableDeclarator Image='' Initializer='false' Name='h'>
                                        <VariableDeclaratorId Array='false' ArrayDepth='0' ArrayType='false' ExceptionBlockParameter='false' ExplicitReceiverParameter='false' Field='false' Final='false' ForeachVariable='false' FormalParameter='false' Image='h' LambdaParameter='false' LocalVariable='true' Name='h' PatternBinding='false' ResourceDeclaration='false' TypeInferred='false' VariableName='h' />
                                    </VariableDeclarator>
                                </LocalVariableDeclaration>
                            </BlockStatement>
                            <BlockStatement Allocation='false' Image=''>
                                <Statement Image=''>
                                    <StatementExpression Image=''>
                                        <PrimaryExpression Image=''>
                                            <PrimaryPrefix Image='' SuperModifier='false' ThisModifier='false'>
                                                <Name Image='z' />
                                            </PrimaryPrefix>
                                        </PrimaryExpression>
                                        <AssignmentOperator Compound='false' Image='=' />
                                        <Expression Image='' StandAlonePrimitive='false'>
                                            <AdditiveExpression Image='+' Operator='+'>
                                                <PrimaryExpression Image=''>
                                                    <PrimaryPrefix Image='' SuperModifier='false' ThisModifier='false'>
                                                        <Name Image='i' />
                                                    </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                </PrimaryExpression>
                                                <PrimaryExpression Image=''>
                                                    <PrimaryPrefix Image='' SuperModifier='false' ThisModifier='false'>
                                                        <Name Image='k' />
                                                    </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                </PrimaryExpression>
                                            </AdditiveExpression>
                                        </Expression>
                                    </StatementExpression>
                                </Statement>
                            </BlockStatement>
                            <BlockStatement Allocation='false' Image=''>
                                <Statement Image=''>
                                    <StatementExpression Image=''>
                                        <PrimaryExpression Image=''>
                                            <PrimaryPrefix Image='' SuperModifier='false' ThisModifier='false'>
                                                <Name Image='h' />
                                            </PrimaryPrefix>
                                        </PrimaryExpression>
                                        <AssignmentOperator Compound='false' Image='=' />
                                        <Expression Image='' StandAlonePrimitive='false'>
                                            <AdditiveExpression Image='+' Operator='+'>
                                                <PrimaryExpression Image=''>
                                                    <PrimaryPrefix Image='' SuperModifier='false' ThisModifier='false'>
                                                        <Name Image='i' />
                                                    </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                </PrimaryExpression>
                                                <PrimaryExpression Image=''>
                                                    <PrimaryPrefix Image='' SuperModifier='false' ThisModifier='false'>
                                                        <Name Image='k' />
                                                    </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                </PrimaryExpression>
                                            </AdditiveExpression>
                                        </Expression>
                                    </StatementExpression>
                                </Statement>
                            </BlockStatement>
                        </Block>
                    </MethodDeclaration>
                </ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration>
            </ClassOrInterfaceBody>
        </ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration>
    </TypeDeclaration>
</CompilationUnit>
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the actual XML. There are a lot of XPath experts on this site, and no doubt plenty of people who know PMD, but they are not all the same people.

Comment: @ConalTuohy  I added a very simple example with XML code. However in my use case the expressions could be nested in loops & branches etc. as well.

Comment: Thanks @Laschoking can you also say what XPath interpreter you have or at least what version of XPath your software supports? The reason I ask is that comparing one AdditiveExpression with another (including all their descendant elements) is relatively easy in later versions of XPath, but if you're relying on an older XPath interpreter you'd need to compare all the descendant elements in a pair-wise fashion, as well.

Comment: @ConaTuohy PMD supports three XPath versions: 1.0, 2.0, and 1.0 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XPath 2 you don't have the handy `deep-equal` function available in version 3 which would allow you to compare two `AdditiveExpression` elements and all their descendants in a single function call. This lack means you have to write something much more verbose, but you could probably get away with something like this:

```xpath
for $e1 in //AdditiveExpression return
$e1[
   some $e2 in (//AdditiveExpression except $e1) satisfies 
      $e1/@Image = $e2/@Image and 
      $e1/PrimaryExpression[1]/PrimaryPrefix/Name/@Image = 
         $e2/PrimaryExpression[1]/PrimaryPrefix/Name/@Image and
      $e1/PrimaryExpression[2]/PrimaryPrefix/Name/@Image = 
         $e2/PrimaryExpression[2]/PrimaryPrefix/Name/@Image
]
```

This XPath 2 expression constructs a sequence of elements that are considered to have duplicates like so:

For every expression ('`$e1`') in the set of `AdditiiveExpression` elements, return that `$e1` if the criterion in the predicate (`[` ... `]`) evaluates to `true`, namely, that there's some other expression ('`$e2`') which is also one of the `AdditiveExpression` elements but isn't `$e1`, and which has the same `Image` attribute as the `$e1` expression, and whose child elements have `Image` attributes that match the corresponding child elements of `$e1`.

I'm not sure what are the important criteria for your two expressions to be considered duplicates; I didn't compare literally every attribute etc, but this should give you an idea.

Comment: running the code above returns following message: "XPath rule expression returned a non-node (class net.sf.saxon.value.BooleanValue): true()".
So I guess it is possible that the rule might be correct & found an expression. Is there a way to output the actual expression?

Comment: OK I was under the impression that the rule should return a boolean, but I guess it should return the actual elements which it thinks are at fault? I will revise it

Comment: I revised the expression so that it returns a sequence of `AdditiveExpression` elements which are a match for at least one other `AdditiveExpression`. NB if there are two `AdditiveExpression` elements that match then this should return both of them.

Comment: On a more general note, I'm not at all familiar with PMD but I've used similar technologies e.g. schematron in an analogous way, in which rules written in XPath are used to flag patterns of concern in XML documents, and on that basis I think you'll find XPath's "quantified expressions" to be really helpful constructs in PMD rules, and worth a look; they are the equivalent of the well-known logical symbols ∀ and ∃ which you may know <https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-quantified-expressions>

Comment: Given that PMD uses Saxon as its XPath interpreter, it's a shame they are stuck on XPath 2.0! If I were you I'd prod them to upgrade it to support 3.1, which would be a simpler upgrade for them than the upgrade from 1.0 to 2.0 I can't help thinking, and is infinitely more expressive (XPath 3.1 is Turing complete!)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your modified answer is exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks also for the reference on quantified expressions, I will check it out.

Comment: You're welcome! thanks for accepting the answer, and thanks also for putting me onto PMD which I hadn't seen before and I think is really fascinating